# C# - Implement abstract or interface method inside of another method

Tags: c#, interface, delegates, abstract

I am trying to implement an abstract or interface method inside of another method based on a switch case. Depending on the index given, I would like to implement a different method.

Code

```
public interface choices    
{    
    void Effect ();    
}

public class Imple : choices    
{    
    public void Choose(int index)    
    {    
        if(index == 1)    
        {    
            void Effect()    
            {    
            // implementation here


            }    
            else if(index == 2)
            // etc.

        }    
    }
}
```

Can it be done by overriding an abstract method?
Thank you.

--- EDIT ---

I understand that the code and explanation provided above is unclear, so I will try to explain better.

I am creating a Unity game, however the problem I have has to do with interfaces and c# method implementation and that is why I did not ask the Unity Forum. For this game, I have weapons that have different properties (stats like damage and intelligence, hands occupied, etc.) that work fine.

Item Class (base class)

```
public class Item
{
    // stats and getters / setters
}
```

Weapon Class

```
public class Weapon : Item
{
    public void Attack()
    {
        // attack enemies and reduce their health
        // I want the Effect method to activate when attacking, 
        // if the method has been implementd
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to create different methods on run time that are able to execute effects, like for example dealing more damage when hitting an enemy. However, I would like to implement these methods on run time based on an index that corresponds to an effect. The reason is that weapons are stored in a json file, and when parsing it this index will help identify which effect a weapon has. So, if the index is 1, the implementation should allow the weapon to deal the extra damage, but if it is 2, it will have a different effect. For this, I have created a OnHit class and a IOnHit interface like this:

```
public class OnHit : IOnHit
{
    public void Effect()
    {
        // empty
    }
}


public interface IOnHit
{
    void Effect();
}
```

I am looking for a way to make that happen dynamically. One way I thought of doing this was to have a static class with all effects and then passing the index there and continuing. However, that would be problematic for the game as it would have to loop through a switch case every time the player attacks (or 2, if the player has 2 weapons). So, I am looking for a way to have an interface or an abstract class with abstract methods that can be implemented once, and then called whenever the effects of the weapon happens. My idea was to create an instance of the OnHit class inside the weapon object and link the IOnHit interface there. Then, to implement the code inside it like this:

```
public class Weapon : Item
{
    OnHit oh = new OnHit();
    IOnHit ioh = oh;
    public void Attack()
    {
        // previous attack method
        if(ioh.Effect is implemented)
            ioh.Effect();
    }

    public void SetIndex(int index)
    {
        switch{
            case 1:
                ioh.Effect()
                {
                    // implementation of the effect
                }
            break;

            case 2:
                ioh.Effect()
                {
                    // implementation of different effect
                }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

where the index parameter is the id of the effect, drawn from the parsed json.

Thank you again.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense at the moment. The interface implementation is for code _outside_ the class to call. Why would you ever have a method inside the class trying to use the interface, never mind doing so in a conditionally-implemented way?

Comment: The original question was very clear. Unfortunately, you can't achieve what you want that way. You must implement the method directly on the class (not nested in another method). Then you could put a switch or if/else inside that uses the value from Choose(), if you store it in a private field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is delegating.

So in the class implementation, you will create two private or protected methods to implement the effect.

Then when you call the `Choose` method it sets the delegate reference field you create too to point to the desired method.

And now your `Effect` method calls the delegate reference if not null (initialized).

```
static void Test()
{
  var instance = new Imple();
  instance.Choose(2);
  instance.Effect();
}

public interface choices
{
  void Effect();
}

public class Imple : choices
{
  private Action SelectedEffect;

  public void Effect()
  {
    if ( SelectedEffect != null ) SelectedEffect();
  }

  private void Effect1()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Effect1 called.");
  }

  private void Effect2()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Effect2 called.");
  }

  public void Choose(int index)
  {
    switch ( index )
    {
      case 1:
        SelectedEffect = Effect1;
        break;
      case 2:
        SelectedEffect = Effect2;
        break;
      default:
        throw new NotImplementedException("Effect version n°" + index);
    }
  }

}
```

`Effect` can point to any method from any class:

```
  case 1:
    SelectedEffect = SomeReference1.SomeMethod;
    break;
  case 2:
    SelectedEffect = SomeReference2.SomeMethod;
    break;
```

You can replace `Action` by any method signature to match parameters and any returning type.

Answer (score -2):

If what you are trying to do is change the behavior of the implementation of `Effect` depending on the parameter passed to `Choose`, then you will have to use a state field to store that and read it in `Effect`, like this

```
public class Imple : choices    
{    
    private int effectNum = 1; // set the default effect here

    public void Choose(int index)    
    {    
        effectNum = index;   
    }

    public void Effect()
    {
        switch (effectNum)
        {
            case 1: // implement the different effects here
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```